# Wordpress woocommerce product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi everyone,

Is there anyways to put product without using product name? My products don't have name. Anyone who can help please respond.

Thanks,

Best Regards.

Comment: In Wordpress the name make the URL of a post type (like products)… So what you can do when you create a product, is to put a name that will generate a slug for this product url. Then save. Then remove the name and re-save…

Comment: Well, I did it but still product name appear. Any idea why?

Comment: No sorry… for me I have maid a try and it has worked

Comment: You need to give the product a name for admin and URL slug purposes. How can a product not have a name? What do you refer to it as? You can always remove the display from the front end via hooks, but again, why?

Comment: Well, I'm doing site for dresses and my boss told  me that his dresses dont have name, i told him that he needs a name for products but he refuse to named products, either way thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility with future updates of your theme and plugins, I've found a better way to do this is through WooCommerce hooks. To remove the title from your Single Product Page, you should put the following two lines in your theme's main functions.php.

in this titla field is not coming on product insert.

```
 remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
```

Other way is but in this your title is coming but you hide that because of you don't want to see that.

```
.woocommerce li.product .entry-header h3 a, .woocommerce-page li.product .entry-header h3 a {
display: none;
}

.woocommerce .price, .woocommerce-page .price {
    display: none;
    }
```

I hope this worth to you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS to do so.In listing page you can use following CSS :

```
ul.products h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title {
    display: none;
}
```

It might be differ base on version.